# 64 bit ODBC Exception

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, odbc, driver, windows-7-x64

I am getting the following ODBC exception when I moved my development platform from Windows XP X86 to Windows 7 X64:

```
ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
```

What I'm sure it means is that the server it is connecting to is 32 bit, and the computer I'm running on is 64 bit and the ODBC driver in use is 64 bit.

The application I am writing is set to run in 32 bit mode because some of the third-party software that we employ is not 64 bit compatible.

I tried downloading a 32 bit driver and changing the DSN but it did not fix my issue.  I still get the exception.

If anyone has any links for 32 bit SQL drivers, or any ideas on how I could fix this by changing the project around, I'm all ears.

Thanks in advance,

-Jrud-

Comment: some1 voted to close my topic may i ask why?

Comment: I'm glad it wasn't closed :) Came in very handy today.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It sounds more that you've setup a 32-bit DSN using the 64-bit ODBC Administrator :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712362(VS.85).aspx

Try using this ODBC Administrator instead :

c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

Comment: Exactly the issue.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Now looking through the control panel, I cannot find a way to get into the 32 bit administrator without going through that directory path... why did microsoft hide the 32 bit administrator? 0_o

Comment: They don't want you to know about it.

Comment: Once again SO saves my day :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you type ODBC from Start -> Search Programs box, it only lists 32bit ODBC administrator, not 64bit console. Microsoft hide 64bit administrator from search.

Comment: No, that is the wrong way round. They show the 64bit ODBC administrator and hide the 32bit.