# Unable to find an entry point named 'InterlockedIncrement' in DLL 'kernel32.dll' - VS2005@Win7 64 bit

Tags: c#, postgresql, 64-bit, odbc, kernel32

I have a problem with my Visual Studio 2005 C# project. I have been using it under Windows XP, since Monday. Then my laptop broke down and on my new one I have Windows 7 64 bit and I am still using VS 2005.

There is no problem with compilation of the source, but when I run the program it breaks on the line below

```
OdbcConnection cn;
cn = new OdbcConnection("dsn=My_dsn_name;");
```

I get the error:

*EnrtyPointNotFoundExcepition was unhalted*

**Unable to find an entry point named 'InterlockedIncrement' in DLL 'kernel32.dll'**

I am trying to connect with a Postgres 8.4 database using PostgresODBC 64 bit driver.

Any solution or workaround is welcome. I need to stress that the solution I am building needs to run under Windows XP 32bit.

Updated information about the issue (from my respones to the comments but not only):

1. When I tried to add new connection to my VS project I got the message **ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application**. I use Windows 7 64 bit, Postgres ODBC 64 bit Driver ver. *9.00.0200*, Postgres 8.4 32 bit.
2. I have never used **Dependency Walker** before. But I have opened *kernel32.dll* from both *\system32* and *\SysWOW64* and **InterlockedIncrement** is present in files from both folders.
3. I have some **TableAdapters**, and I use them to fetch data from the Postgres. It was set when I was using WinXP, and it still works. On the other hand, when in VS2005 in the properties of **TableAdapter** I click on "**...**" next to **Data->CommandText** it displays a message Failed to call the ODBC driver connection utility.

EDIT: I added points 1-3 above.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. Could you check with Dependency Viewer that the supposedly missing export is present in kernel32.dll (both in C:\Windows\system32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64).

Comment: I have never used *Dependency Walker* before. But I have opened **kernel32.dll** from both *\system32* and *\SysWOW64* and **InterlockedIncrement** is present in files from both folders.

Comment: You're using the 32-bit version of depends.exe - the 32-bit version always loads the c:\system\syswow64 version of kernel32.dll, even if you try to load the 64-bit one. Try the 64-bit version of depends.exe and you will see that these exports are missing from the 64-bit version of kernel32.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have solved problem, although I am not sure. However, I installed the 32bit version of Postgres ODBC driver **and** I used 32bit version of ODBC administrator **C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe** to configure the connection. I found the information about the 32bit ODBC Administrator in the thread [64-bit-odbc-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947634/64-bit-odbc-exception) where one of the users refers to [MSDN: Managing Data Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712362%28VS.85%29.aspx).

I thought that I needed the same version of ODBC driver (regarting to number of bits) as my OS. I have also tried 64bit version of Postgres and ODBC driver, but it also did not want to work for me. The only solution was 32bit version of Postgres, and ODBC, and **connection set** in **32bit ODBC Administrator**.

Regarding my VS project, I have *Project->Properties->Build->Platform target* set to **x86**.

Hope it helps somebody in the future.

Answer (score 5):

On 64 bit windows these are not real functions exported from kernel32.dll - they are compiler intrinsics instead. The code that is P/Invoking that function should be using the Interlocked managed class instead.

They are intrinsics on 32-bit windows too nowadays, but the exported functions are still available from kernel32.dll on 32-bit windows for app compat reasons. Not a problem for 64 bit because there were no apps to be compatible with.

Comment: Well, in my 64 bit Windows, kernel32 has these exports. Indeed MSDN clearly documents it as so. So I don't believe this.

Comment: Mine doesn't. Remember there are two versions of kernel32.dll on a 64-bit Windows system - the 32-bit one, which lives in c:\windows\SysWOW64, which has InterlockedIncrement, and the 64-bit one in c:\windows\system32 which doesn't. You're probably using the 32-bit version of depends.exe, which for some reason (probably file redirection - and if it is file redirection this is probably a bug in depends.exe) loads the 32-bit version of the DLL even if you load it from c:\windows\system32

Comment: Mine, Dependency Walker for Win32 ver 2.1.3790 run under Win7 64bit, shows that kernel32.dll in both folders has InterlockedIncrement. It does not load 32 bit version as it shows the path to the investigated file, and it differs in both cases.

Comment: @Stewart Yes you are right! File dialogs in 32 bit programs cannot reach 64 bit system folder other than through sysnative. I knew that but forgot it! Load it through sysnative and these exports are indeed missing.

Comment: I have downloaded 64bit version and you are right! I would have never expected it, but it is true. Anyway, the 64bit version is available for download from http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Removing the functions from kernel32.dll makes sense - the windows code doesn't use them because the microsoft compiler implements this as an intrinsic, and really all compilers should because calling the functions is expensive compared with the operation itself. 32-bit windows had to worry about compatibility with Windows 95 and apps written to work on a 386 where these operations could not be compiler intrinsics as the were more complex than that.

Answer (score 5):

I have just had exactly the same issue, and found a surprisingly simple solution:
Use System.Data.Odbc instead of Microsoft.Data.Odbc in the imports.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is there's something wrong with your driver.  I can't be sure, but you might want to consider using something else.  [Npgsql](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/) looks pretty decent, and it's 100% C# code, so it should work on Windows XP 32-bit without any issues.

Comment: I do not know if it is a driver issue. However, I have some **TableAdapters**, and I use them to fetch data from the **Postgres**. It was set when I was using WinXP, and it still works. On the other hand, when in *VS2005* in the properties of **TableAdapter** I click on **...** next to *Data->CommandText* it displays a message **Failed to call the ODBC driver connection utility**.