# VBA kernel32 InterlockedIncrement not available in 64 bit host, what should I do?

Tags: vba, winapi, 32bit-64bit, kernel32, interlocked-increment

I'm in the process of upgrading some code from 32 to 64 bit VBA. It uses the InterlockedIncrement function:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function InterlockedIncrement Lib "kernel32" (ByRef Addend As Long) As Long
```

This was formerly exported by kernel32 but only for x86 callers. Running from 64-bit Excel it's not so simple, I get a "*Can't find DLL entry point InterlockedIncrement in kernel32*" error - [here's the reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5339349/6609896) I found:

> On 64 bit windows these are not real functions [...] they are compiler
> intrinsics instead. The code that is P/Invoking that function should
> be using the Interlocked managed class

What's a good alternative/ can I fix this?

---

For context, I'm updating the code from [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261264/implement-python-like-generator-using-custom-enumerator-in-vba#:%7E:text=here%0AEnd%20Sub-,MEnumerator.bas,-Save%20this%20to) where InterlockedIncrement & InterlockedDecrement are used to do COM reference counting. Now I understand these Interlocked functions are atomic operations which is important for multithreading, however since VBA runs in a single threaded apartment do I even need to bother? Is `this.refCount = this.refCount + 1` sufficient? The code is slightly above my head so I can't be 100% certain that I won't introduce a bug by forgetting about these functions but let me know either way.

Comment: Yeah you don't need this in vba code because it isn't going to face thread contention

Answer (score -1):

Single threaded drop-in replacements

```
Private Function InterlockedIncrement(ByRef Addend As Long) As Long
    Addend = Addend + 1
    InterlockedIncrement = Addend
End Function

Private Function InterlockedDecrement(ByRef Addend As Long) As Long
    Addend = Addend - 1
    InterlockedDecrement = Addend
End Function
```