# Odbc Error The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch?

Tags: vb.net, odbc, database-connection

I have a 64bit Progress OpenEdge 10.2A driver installed. The connection works fine when I set it up in the Data Sources (ODBC) administrator and test it.

When I try to connect to it using VB.NET (System.Data.Odbc), I get an error:

> ERROR [IM014][Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN
>   contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application.

I have tried manually configuring the registry keys to allow access using SysWOW6432. But all this does is cause another error when I try to set up a DSN. I get error #193 from Progress.

What else could be causing this issue? From what I can tell, I have the proper driver, and the application through which I am using the VB.NET script is configured properly as well.

Any thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [64 bit ODBC Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947634/64-bit-odbc-exception)

Answer (score 0):

I was investigating a similar issue using a different driver and came across this article: http://www.easysoft.com/support/kb/kb01028.html
Not sure if it gives you any further help.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same type of issue with System.Data.Odbc trying to connect to a 32-bit DSN on a 64-bit machine (C# though, not VB).  I set the target platform to x86 and recompiled the project and that resolved the problem. It appears that if you don't specify the build it will automatically try to connect to the default - 64-bit DSN on a 64-bit machine, 32-bit DSN on a 32-bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Properties 
**Compile:**

Configuration  change to All Configuration

Uncheck Prefer 32-bit

### Re-build and Done!!